# Как сделать оффлайн страницу на vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Почитав информацию в интернете, я нашёл один [гайд](https://tproger.ru/translations/browser-offline-page/). И меня озадачило пару вещей, я использую vue и vue-router, html страниц отдельных таковых нет (в плане /offline**.html**) и как тогда мне быть?

Comment: Когда нет отдельных страниц (SPA), продакшн-сборка приложения построенного с Vue и vue-router уже сама по себе является оффлайн-страницей (и каких-то доп. действий, помимо адекватной конфигурации путей/URL - не требуется. Разве что уведомления можно добавить, оповещая юзера о невозможности выполнить AJAX-запрос, когда у него соединение с интернетом отсутствует...). Если же вопрос о PWA (а это чуток другое чем страница работающая в оффлайне) - то он непонятен.

Comment: То есть, когда цель просто в обеспечении работоспособности SPA при отсутствии у юзера соединения с интернетом - по идее, можно обойтись одними заголовками HTTP-ответа: заставляя браузер кэшировать все нужные приложению ассеты (это больше о настройке HTTP-сервера, чем о Vue и фронтэнде в общем). А вот PWA использует другой подход: вместо кэширования выполняется локальная "установка" вебприложения (это тоже позволяет достичь оффлайн-доступности и какой-то работоспособности приложения без соединения с инетом, но уже другим путем).